# MS Sql query to retrieve data for every 15 min intervals of time

Tags: sql-server

Im using MS Sql Server 2008 r2 Database . I tried to get data from database every 15 minutes interval . So i tried this query

***My table name is records and i have columns like Date, Temperature, Pressure***

```
SELECT MIN([Date]) AS Rext 
  FROM Records where Date between '2017-01-27 00:00:00' and '2017-02-11 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]),
  DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]),
  DATEPART(DAY, [Date]),
  DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]),
  (DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) / 15)
  ORDER BY Rext
```

This query is worked for me and im getting date column with 15 intervals time gap .This is my output

```
2017-01-27 18:45:43.000
2017-01-27 19:00:35.000
2017-01-27 19:15:35.000
2017-01-27 19:30:35.000
2017-01-27 19:45:35.000
2017-01-27 20:00:35.000
2017-01-27 20:15:35.000
2017-01-27 20:30:35.000
2017-01-27 20:45:35.000
```

**But when i tried to retrieve other columns(Temperature and Pressure) along with date column im getting output but interval is mismatching . My query be like**

```
SELECT MIN([Date]) AS Rext , Temperature, Pressure
  FROM Records where Date between '2017-01-27 00:00:00' and '2017-02-11 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]),
  DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]),
  DATEPART(DAY, [Date]),
  DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]),
  (DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) / 15)
  ORDER BY Rext,Temperature, Pressure
```

And My Output is

```
2017-01-27 18:45:43.000 18.1        57        
2017-01-27 18:46:43.000 17.9        57        
2017-01-27 18:47:43.000 17.9        58        
2017-01-27 18:50:35.000 18          57        
2017-01-27 19:00:35.000 18          57        
2017-01-27 19:03:35.000 17.9        57        
2017-01-27 19:15:35.000 18.1        57        
2017-01-27 19:16:35.000 18          57        
2017-01-27 19:21:35.000 17.9        57        
2017-01-27 19:30:35.000 18          57        
2017-01-27 19:31:35.000 18.1        57        
2017-01-27 19:33:35.000 17.9        57        
2017-01-27 19:38:35.000 17.9        58        
2017-01-27 19:39:34.000 17.9        56        
2017-01-27 19:40:35.000 17.8        54        
2017-01-27 19:41:35.000 17.9        53        
2017-01-27 19:42:35.000 18          49        
2017-01-27 19:43:35.000 17.9        49        
2017-01-27 19:44:35.000 18          46        
2017-01-27 19:45:35.000 17.9        43        
2017-01-27 19:46:35.000 18          42        
2017-01-27 19:47:35.000 17.9        40        
2017-01-27 19:48:34.000 18          39        
2017-01-27 19:49:35.000 18.1        37        
2017-01-27 19:50:35.000 18.3        36        
2017-01-27 19:51:35.000 18.5        34        
2017-01-27 19:52:35.000 18.6        33        
2017-01-27 19:53:35.000 18.7        31        
2017-01-27 19:54:35.000 18.8        30        
2017-01-27 19:55:35.000 19.1        29        
2017-01-27 19:56:35.000 19.3        28        
2017-01-27 19:58:35.000 19.5        27        
2017-01-27 19:59:35.000 19.6        27        
2017-01-27 20:00:35.000 19.7        26        
2017-01-27 20:01:34.000 19.5        26        
2017-01-27 20:02:35.000 19.4        26        
2017-01-27 20:04:35.000 19.5        25        
2017-01-27 20:06:35.000 19.4        25        
2017-01-27 20:07:35.000 19.3        25        
2017-01-27 20:15:35.000 19.4        25        
2017-01-27 20:16:34.000 19.3        25        
2017-01-27 20:18:35.000 19.5        25        
2017-01-27 20:20:35.000 19.5        24        
2017-01-27 20:21:35.000 19.3        24        
2017-01-27 20:22:35.000 19.4        24        
2017-01-27 20:28:35.000 19.6        24        
2017-01-27 20:30:35.000 19.6        24        
2017-01-27 20:31:35.000 19.5        24        
2017-01-27 20:35:35.000 19.4        24        
2017-01-27 20:45:35.000 19.6        24        
2017-01-27 20:47:35.000 19.5        24        
2017-01-27 21:00:35.000 19.5        24        
2017-01-27 21:01:35.000 19.6        23        
2017-01-27 21:05:47.000 19.7        23        
2017-01-27 21:14:47.000 19.8        23        
2017-01-27 21:15:47.000 19.7        23        
2017-01-27 21:16:47.000 19.8        23        
2017-01-27 21:20:47.000 19.8        22
```

Please any one help me .  THANK YOU

Comment: Shortcut: Whenever you use Aggregate condition all other columns (Non Aggregate) in select should come in  Group by clause.

Comment: Your query as posted would result in an error.   Please post the actual query that is generating the results you say you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,Date)/15*15,0) AS Rext , MIN(Temperature), MAX(Pressure)
  FROM Records where Date between '2017-01-27 00:00:00' and '2017-02-11 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,Date)/15*15,0), Temperature, Pressure
  ORDER BY 1
```

**Shortcut:** Whenever you use Aggregate condition all other columns (Non Aggregate) in select should be in Group by clause

Comment: I too tried this what you have suggested to me but interval is not comming in correct way

Comment: Try to round off the date so that group by clause will work perfectly. DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,dt)/15*15,0). You can refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8364f9c8-65c6-4297-b9ff-5c2cf39ead4b/round-up-datetime-in-15-minute-increments?forum=ssdt